# GWT: Tomcat can't serialize 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException'

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, gwt

In my workplace I was testing a GWT webapp using Tomcat 6 + Java 6 (I think) and worked perfectly, but today IT upgraded to Java 7 (java -version output) and now I'm receiving the following errors in catalina.out when I try to open my webapp (the layout in index.html works perfectly):

> GRAVE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:130)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:393)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
>           at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>           at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any ideas? Can I do something from my side or this is a problem IT should solve?

Code related to the SSLException. [Source](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all()).build();
```

Comment: I think a connection Exception was thrown on the server side and what you posted is GWT trying to convert SSLException to javascript. So it's a Java error and not a GWT error

Comment: Yep, I managed to get the same conclusion yesterday.

The problem is the code was working a few days ago and nothing relevant was changed, so I'm not sure if it's got something to do with Java7 (Maybe related? [Thread](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/472065)). I'll update my question with the relevant code (the only code from where a SSLException can be thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found the answer!](http://blog.backslasher.net/java-ssl-crash.html) Upgrading `nss` package solved the problem (had to ask IT to upgrade it).

Answer (score 0):

When a GWT app is compiled the code is analysed and a whole load of Javascript generated to run on the client. For objects that are sent from the server to the client GWT generates Javascript versions of all the classes it thinks it needs. It does so by looking at the code.

In your case you may find that the code declares that it throws an IOException so GWT has generated support for this on the client. But the code is throwing an SSLException, a sub class of IOException which GWT has not generated any client side code hence the com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException. It is likely this issue has always been present but it now being seen because you have SSL issues.

So, you may be able to avoid the issue by sorting out the SSL issues which are likely to be environmental- but it is likely the GWT app needs to be looked at to sort out its handling of serialisation of exceptions.

Comment: The problem is in my local enviroment everything works, with previous code and with new code using `PrivateKey key = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION), "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");` , I can only test that exception on remote web server, so I need to GWT Compile entire project, and then the exception doesn't get serialized.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should repost this as a SSLException/KeyException question, but since it's working on local environment, I'm not completely sure about that.